# Load and animate huge images

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have some huge image size which is animated, scrolling to the left. The performance is very bad. I would like to have only 2 images at the beginning. Then user clicks on the left or right arrow i need to show a loader image then pull the images. Is that possible? how? please tell if there are any other way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not the answer that you where looking for but I think that you should only use a simple animation (fade or something else), why?, because the performance of the animation depends to much on the browser the pc (or device) running the browser, the version of the browser, I used to waste a lot of time trying to fix all performance problems on all the browsers.